# How can I make a table for shapley values with Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I made a random forest regression with filter for y and x variables and I also wanted to add more about shapley values by creating a graph and table with column for the variable and column for the shaply value result. The code plots the graph, but the table is not showing.
So far my code looks like this:

```
x=widgets.SelectMultiple(
                options=list(dataset.select_dtypes('number').columns),
                disabled=False,
                value=("NUMBER_SPOTS",)
                )

def randomforest(y, x):

    x = dataset[list(x)]
    y = dataset[y]
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    shap.initjs()
 
    model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

    mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict)**(0.5)

    print('Mean Squared Error:', mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict)**(0.5))

    explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

    shap.summary_plot(shap_values, features=X_train, feature_names=X_train.columns, plot_size=[15,8])
    
    shap_vals = shap_values[0, :]
    feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(X_train.columns, shap_vals)), columns=['X_train', 'shap_vals'])
    feature_importance.sort_values(by=['shap_vals'], ascending=False,inplace=True)
    feature_importance

interact(randomforest, y = list(dataset.select_dtypes('number').columns), x = x)
```

Comment: You want to show/print `feature_importance` array ??

Comment: Probably need to return or explicitly print yout last line in the function randomforest()

Comment: Thank you SidoShiro92, it works! Such as simple solution and yet it managed to challenge me.